# PyGRASS error: Could not load grass_gis.8.2

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script, pygrass

In PyGRASS I can only import objects from the module `modules`:

```py
from grass_session import Session
from grass.pygrass.modules import Module, MultiModule, ParallelModuleQueue

print(Module)
```

If I'm trying to import other PyGRASS modules like `vector` I am getting an error:

```py
from grass_session import Session
from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonas.frei/Documents/Python/pygrass01/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
  File "/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/etc/python/grass/pygrass/vector/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import grass.lib.gis as libgis
  File "/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/etc/python/grass/lib/gis.py", line 30, in <module>
    _libs["grass_gis.8.2"] = load_library("grass_gis.8.2")
  File "/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/etc/python/grass/lib/ctypes_loader.py", line 105, in __call__
    raise ImportError("Could not load %s." % libname)
ImportError: Could not load grass_gis.8.2.
```

I already tried to fix this error in so many ways:

- MacOS, GRASS GIS 8.2, grass_session
- MacOS, GRASS GIS 8.2, ['Python: GRASS GIS 7 without existing location using metadata only'-script](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Important_notes)
- Windows, GRASS GIS 8.2, grass_session
- Windows, GRASS GIS 7.8, grass_session

I'm using the following environment variables:

- MacOS

  - GRASSBIN=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/grass
  - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/lib
  - GISBASE=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources
  - PATH="$PATH:/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/bin"
- Windows

  - PATH=%PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W\bin
  - GRASSBIN=C:\OSGeo4W\bin\grass78
  - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\lib
  - GISBASE=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let me recommend to use GRASS GIS 8 (and no longer 7.8).

So, in a running GRASS GIS 8 session, run in `python`:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

# define GRASS data settings (adapt to your needs)
grassdata = "/home/mneteler/grassdata/"
location = "nc_spm_08_grass7"
mapset = "user1"

# Python path: we ask GRASS GIS where its Python packages are
sys.path.append(
    subprocess.check_output(["grass", "--config", "python_path"], text=True).strip()
)

# Import GRASS Python bindings
import grass.script as gs
import grass.script.setup as gsetup

# Start GRASS Session
session = gsetup.init(grassdata, location, mapset)
```

At this point we are in a running GRASS GIS session, let's verify.

```
# show current GRASS GIS settings
print(gs.read_command("g.gisenv"))
```

Now we may also import further functionality (e.g. [VectorTopo of pygrass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/libpython/grass.pygrass.vector.html?highlight=vectortopo)):

```
from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
```

and can for example retrieve the topology of a vector map (using the [North Carolina dataset](https://grass.osgeo.org/download/data/#NorthCarolinaDataset)):

```
test_vect = VectorTopo("zipcodes_wake")
test_vect.open(mode="r")
test_vect.num_primitive_of("point")
test_vect.num_primitive_of("line")
test_vect.num_primitive_of("centroid")
test_vect.num_primitive_of("boundary")
test_vect.close()
```

This should report:

```
>>> test_vect.num_primitive_of('point')
0
>>> test_vect.num_primitive_of('line')
0
>>> test_vect.num_primitive_of('centroid')
48
>>> test_vect.num_primitive_of('boundary')
158
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your hint that I have to start GRASS GIS first solved my problem. I thought that I can use PyGRASS standalone in my own python distribution. However, according to the documentation, this does not seem to be the case: ["The only action before starting to work with PyGRASS is to launch GRASS GIS 8 and from the console launch python"](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/libpython/pygrass_index.html)

Comment: Instead of running the code in an open GRASS GIS session, you can also perform the "Execution of shell and Python scripts instead of single commands" - see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/grass.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface (using `grass ... --exec your_script.py`).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the missing GRASS GIS libraries into your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or on OSX it will be: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)

You can add it on top of your script:

```py
import os

os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/lib/grass82/lib/'
```

Then MarkusN example will also work in a standalone script or in a jupyter notebook. [see example](https://gist.github.com/epifanio/31ec2bc95992cae1b3091f64aed06e66) (assumes grass-session is installed)